# Обновление представления при изменении ObservableCollection?

Tags: c#, wpf

Имеется во View  элемент ListBox который биндится до  ObservableCollection, при открытии страницы первый раз, все отлично работает, но при изменении его во View ничего не меняется , хотя дебагер говорит что значение изменено, как обновить View из ViewModel??

```
 public ObservableCollection<ChartConfigList> SomeCollectionView
    {
        get { return LeftList; }
        set { LeftList = value; }
    }
```

private ObservableCollection SomeList = new ObservableCollection();

Answer (score 2):

`ObservableCollection` отправляет событие, когда элемент добавляется или удаляется из коллекции. Когда подменяется *сама* коллекция, отправлять событие нужно вашему коду. Ваш сеттер должен отправлять `PropertyChanged`, а VM-класс — имплементировать `INotifyPropertyChanged`

Answer (score 2):

Другое решение - не заменять коллекцию на новую, а вызывать метод `Clear()`

PS. Setter при этом стоит сделать приватным (а лучше вообще избавиться от него и создавать коллекцию один раз в конструкторе)